# How to conditionally add code in head of Vue app

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, google-tag-manager, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I have made a simple Vue app using the Vue CLI and now I want to add Google Tag Manager code in the head of the html conditionally only for the production build. I could do this with a server side language like php so I tried changing the index.html to index.php but when I build the project it outputs an index.html with the app injected and the index.php without the app injected in the dist folder. The php code also doesn't work with the webpack-dev-server in the vue cli.

How can I integrate some server side code (it doesn't have to be php) into the index of the vue app generated by the vue cli to conditionally add the tag manager code for the production build? I'm not sure how the vue cli build process is done. Can I tell it to use a different index.html for the production build?

Extra: I'm interested in knowing more about the vue cli build process. ex. There is no script tag in the template index.html so how does Vue inject itself into the index when building or using the webpack-dev-server?

Comment: please pay attention that you should have two index.hmtl files: one template and one bundled. The bundled one should be in your src folder and it contains the js and css files with chunkhashes at their end. The template one is in your root folder (where your package.json resides). Maybe you already know that but there is a complete guide for server-side rendering in Vue.js: https://ssr.vuejs.org/

Comment: There is a plugin called vue-analytics especially for the purpose that you want. In the plugin, there is an option to turn it off during development, you should check this out: https://matteogabriele.gitbooks.io/vue-analytics/content/docs/turn-off-development.html

Comment: @MátéWiszt I'd like to avoid having to modify the bundled index.html after building. I'm going to have to look into SSR vs PHP server load.  Thanks for the link to the plugin.

Comment: Yes, you should never modify the bundled index.html because it will be always auto-generated so all your edits will be gone, I just referred to it to raise your attention to the template one where you can add things.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just saw in the [vue cli documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#interpolation) that the index.html page is processed by webpack. This means I can use lodash template syntax to easily add tags in the head only on production

```
<head>
...
<%= process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '<script>...</script>' : '' %>
...
</head>
```

Comment: @AlexanderKim, its working on `v 3.2.1` so it should work on `v 3.0.5`...

Comment: The more important question is: do this syntax also work in .vue components?
I want to create some builds flags and conditionally print html in the <template tag> or scripts in the <script> tag, would that work?

Comment: Interesting solution, but it is worth mentioning that it won't be possible to nest another `process.env` variable in the `<script>` tag. @undroid-system solution will allow nesting though.

Comment: what if its Vite instead of webpack

Answer (score 12):

alternative method:

```
<% if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>
    <script>...</script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this library, it allows for conditional pre-processing:

[js-conditional-compile-loader](https://github.com/hzsrc/js-conditional-compile-loader)